# why don't the names change to those that were specified in the date frame?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, ttr

I wrote a simple function that combines all indicators from the TTR package, but not all indicators have names that have changed as I specified in the dataframe.

for example, `TTR::chaikinVolatility` indicator has not changed its name, as well as some others that I indicated in the comments inside the function

```
data.frame(
  ..
  ..
  chaikinVolatility = TTR::chaikinVolatility(HL = HL, n = n), # why colname 'EMA' not chaikinVolatility ?
  ..
  ..
 )
```

Here is my complete function

```
get_all_indicators <- function(p, n= 10){
CLOSE <- quantmod::Cl(p)
OHLC <-  quantmod::OHLC(p)
HLC <-   quantmod::HLC(p)
HL <-    quantmod::HL(p)
VOLUME <- quantmod::Vo(p)


data.frame(
  
  ADX =    TTR::ADX(HLC = HLC, n = n),
  ALMA =   TTR::ALMA(OHLC, n = n),
  aroon =  TTR::aroon(HL = HL, n = n),
  ATR =    TTR::ATR(HLC = HLC, n = n),
  BBands = TTR::BBands(HLC = HLC, n = n),
  CCI =    TTR::CCI(HLC = HLC, n = n),
  chaikinAD = TTR::chaikinAD(HLC = HLC, volume = VOLUME),
  chaikinVolatility = TTR::chaikinVolatility(HL = HL, n = n), # why colname 'EMA' not chaikinVolatility ?
  CLV =   TTR::CLV(HLC = HLC),
  CMF =   TTR::CMF(HLC = HLC, n = n, volume = VOLUME),
  CMO =   TTR::CMO(x = CLOSE, n = n),
  CTI =   TTR::CTI(price = CLOSE, n = n),
  DEMA =  TTR::DEMA(x = CLOSE,n = n),
  DonchianChannel = TTR::DonchianChannel(HL = HL,n = n),
  DPO =   TTR::DPO(x = CLOSE, n = n),  #---------------------- why colname 'close' not DPO ?
  DVI =   TTR::DVI(price = CLOSE, n = n),
  EMA =   TTR::EMA(x = CLOSE, n = n),   #---------------------- colname 'EMA.1' not EMA 
  EVWMA = TTR::EVWMA(price = CLOSE, n = n, volume = VOLUME),
  HMA =   TTR::HMA(CLOSE, n = n),
  keltnerChannels = TTR::keltnerChannels(HLC = HLC, n = n),
  KST =   TTR::KST(CLOSE, n = n),
  MACD =  TTR::MACD(x = CLOSE,nFast = n, nSlow = n*2),
  MFI =   TTR::MFI(HLC = HLC, n = n, volume = VOLUME),
  momentum = TTR::momentum(CLOSE, n = n),  #-------------------why colname "Close.1"  not  momentum?
  OBV =   TTR::OBV(CLOSE,volume = VOLUME),
  PBands =TTR::PBands(CLOSE, n = n),
  ROC =   TTR::ROC(OHLC, n = n),
  RSI =   TTR::RSI(CLOSE, n),
  SAR =   TTR::SAR(HL = HL),
  SMA =   TTR::SMA(x = CLOSE, n = n),
  SMI =   TTR::SMI(HLC = HLC, n = n, nFast = n, nSlow = n*2),
  SNR =   TTR::SNR(HLC = HLC, n = n), #-------------------why colname "Close.2"  not  SNR?
  stoch = TTR::stoch(HLC = HLC, nFastK = n, nFastD = n, nSlowD = n*2),
  TDI =   TTR::TDI(CLOSE,n = n),
  TR =    TTR::TR(HLC = HLC),
  TRIX =  TTR::TRIX(price = CLOSE, n = n),
  VHF =   TTR::VHF(price = CLOSE, n = n),
  volatility = TTR::volatility(OHLC = OHLC, n = n),
  williamsAD = TTR::williamsAD(HLC = HLC),
  WPR = TTR::WPR(HLC = HLC, n = n)  #-------------------why colname "Close.3"  not  WPR?
)
}
```

Here is the code to fully launch the function

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
n <- 10000
     
# make some fake praces
prices <- cumsum(rnorm(n,sd = 0.01)) |> 
           round(2) |> 
           cbind(price = _, volume = sample(1:1000,n,T)) |> 
           xts(Sys.time()-n:1) |> 
           to.minutes(name = "my_prices") +10000

colnames(prices) <- gsub("^my_prices\\.", "", colnames(prices))
# head(prices)
# chart_Series(prices)

gai <- get_all_indicators(p = prices)
colnames(gai)
```

---

```
colnames(gai)
 [1] "ADX.DIp"              "ADX.DIn"              "ADX.DX"               "ADX.ADX"             
 [5] "ALMA.Open"            "ALMA.High"            "ALMA.Low"             "ALMA.Close"          
 [9] "aroon.aroonUp"        "aroon.aroonDn"        "aroon.oscillator"     "ATR.tr"              
[13] "ATR.atr"              "ATR.trueHigh"         "ATR.trueLow"          "BBands.dn"           
[17] "BBands.mavg"          "BBands.up"            "BBands.pctB"          "cci"                 
[21] "chaikinAD"            "EMA"                  "clv"                  "CMF"                 
[25] "cmo"                  "cti"                  "DEMA"                 "DonchianChannel.high"
[29] "DonchianChannel.mid"  "DonchianChannel.low"  "Close"                "DVI.dvi.mag"         
[33] "DVI.dvi.str"          "DVI.dvi"              "EMA.1"                "EVWMA"               
[37] "HMA"                  "keltnerChannels.dn"   "keltnerChannels.mavg" "keltnerChannels.up"  
[41] "KST.kst"              "KST.signal"           "MACD.macd"            "MACD.signal"         
[45] "mfi"                  "Close.1"              "obv"                  "PBands.dn"           
[49] "PBands.center"        "PBands.up"            "ROC.Open"             "ROC.High"            
[53] "ROC.Low"              "ROC.Close"            "rsi"                  "sar"                 
[57] "SMA"                  "SMI.SMI"              "SMI.signal"           "Close.2"             
[61] "stoch.fastK"          "stoch.fastD"          "stoch.slowD"          "TDI.tdi"             
[65] "TDI.di"               "TR.tr"                "TR.trueHigh"          "TR.trueLow"          
[69] "TRIX.TRIX"            "TRIX.signal"          "VHF"                  "volatility"          
[73] "williamsAD"           "Close.3"
```

What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that you are having problems with return `xts` objects rather than simple vectors. When those are coerced into data.frames they keep their special names. You can drop the default names by extracing the core data from the `xts` object and explictly unnaming it

```
  data.frame(
    chaikinVolatility = unname(coredata(TTR::chaikinVolatility(HL = HL, n = n))),
    DPO =   unname(coredata(TTR::DPO(x = CLOSE, n = n))),
    EMA =   unname(coredata(TTR::EMA(x = CLOSE, n = n))),
    momentum = unname(coredata(TTR::momentum(CLOSE, n = n))),
    SNR =   unname(coredata(TTR::SNR(HLC = HLC, n = n))),
    WPR = unname(coredata(TTR::WPR(HLC = HLC, n = n)))
  )
```

Comment: But some indicators return multiple columns and I need their real names like `"ATR.tr"              
[13] "ATR.atr"              "ATR.trueHigh"         "ATR.trueLow"`

Comment: Then only use `unname(coredata(...))` on the columns you want to rename. Here I only used them on the "problem" columns you identified. You can put all the other ones back in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand right away